# installation of matlab r2011a in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation

I have installation folder which i used for windows 7 of Matlab r2011a, which contains setup.exe file and how to install it in Ubuntu 13.10. new to Ubuntu environment

Answer (score 0):

exe files are stuff from Windows. They only work on Ubuntu with a compatibility layer, such as WINE.

To install Matlab in Ubuntu, install it from the software center.